# Is it possible to join academia with a structured PhD?

Tags: phd, germany

There are [two types of PhDs](https://www.uni-muenster.de/forschung/en/promotion/strukturiertepromotion.html) in Germany(or, in other parts of the world, like, Ireland): structured, and individual.

A [definition of structured Ph.D.](https://www.quora.com/What-is-exactly-a-structured-PhD-program-and-how-different-is-it-from-a-conventional-PhD) is as follows:

> Usually, in structured Ph.D. programs, the thesis advisor has a
>   pre-planned or a pre-defined research proposal which he intends on
>   carrying forward through his Ph.D. student. The Ph.D. student then
>   does some preliminary studies based on this proposal, based on which
>   the student sets his own objectives. Basically, in such structured
>   programs, a few of the objectives are already set and the may, or may
>   not add a few more, depending on some of the results obtained in his
>   preliminary work.

Is it possible to join academia with a structured Ph.D.?

Answer (score 7):

In practice the distinction is gradual. Some structured programs don't function as well as advertised, meaning that the PhD students are pretty much left on their own, while some advisors of individual PhD project are very structured. Sometimes individual PhD students can participate in (parts of) a structured program, etc. etc.

In the end if you get a PhD, then you got a PhD regardless of the type of program. No one will know, and no one will care one way or another. In practice a well functioning structured program is beneficial as the students tend to learn more and the network of a given cohort in such a program tends to help as well.